# NullPointerException when multiple classes are run in TestNG

Tags: maven, nullpointerexception, testng

I have been trying to execute multiple classes in TestNG.xml but immediately get NullPointerException. But the same test passes when executed individually using Run as TestNG Test. I have added all codes used in various classes and property files.

**Error message:**

```
    org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: com.w2a.testcases.BankManagerLogin
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:575)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Below is the testng.xml file details:

```
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Data Driven">
    <test name="Bank Manager Login Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.w2a.testcases.BankManagerLogin"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Adding Customer Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.w2a.testcases.AddCustomerTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**BankManagerLogin class**

```
    public class BankManagerLogin extends TestBase{

    @Test
    public void loginAsBankManager() throws Exception 
    {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty("BNKButton"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

    }

}
```

**AddCustomerTest class**

```
public class AddCustomerTest extends TestBase {

    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void AddCustomer(String firstName, String lastName, String postCode) throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty("addCustButton1"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty("firstName"))).sendKeys(firstName);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty("lastName"))).sendKeys(lastName);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty("postCode"))).sendKeys(postCode);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty("addCustButton2"))).click();
    }


    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        String sheetName="AddCustomerTest";
        int rows= excel.getRowCount(sheetName);
        int cols= excel.getColumnCount(sheetName);
        Object[][] data = new Object[rows-1][cols];

        for (int rowNum=2; rowNum<=rows; rowNum++)
        {
            for (int col_Num=0; col_Num<cols; col_Num++)
            {
                data[rowNum-2][col_Num]= excel.getCellData(sheetName, col_Num, rowNum);
            }
        }
        return data;


    }

}
```

Have a BaseClass to define @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite:

```
public class TestBase {

    public  WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties config = new Properties();
    public static Properties OR = new Properties();
    public static FileInputStream fis;
    public static ExcelReader excel =new ExcelReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\excel\\testdata.xlsx");



    //public static Logger log=Logger.get

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp()
    {
        if(driver==null)
        {

            try{
                fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\properties\\config.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();}
                try {
                    config.load(fis);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {

                fis= new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\properties\\OR.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();}
                try {
                    OR.load(fis);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



                if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome"))
                {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
                    driver= new ChromeDriver();
                    //log.debug("Chrome launched");
                }
                else if

                (config.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox"))
                {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\geckodriver.exe");
                    driver= new FirefoxDriver();
                    //log.debug("Firefox launched");
                }

                else if

                (config.getProperty("browser").equals("IE"))
                {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.IE.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                    driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    //log.debug("Internet Explorer launched");
                }

                driver.get(config.getProperty("testSiteurl"));
                //log.debug("Navigated to: "+config.getProperty("testSiteURL"));
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("implicit.wait")), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }


    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

******Object property file:******

```
    #Bank Manager Login button
BankManagerLogin=div > div:last-child > .btn.btn-primary.btn-lg

#Add Customer button
addCustomerButton=button[ng-click='addCust()']

#customer details
addCustButton1=button[ng-click='addCust()']
firstName=input[ng-model='fName']
lastName=input[ng-model='lName']
postCode=input[ng-model='postCd']


#click add customer button on form
addCustButton2=button[class='btn btn-default']
```

******Config property file:******

```
browser=chrome
testSiteURL=http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/login
implicit.wait=10
```

Comment: Can you try this... Eclipse > Project > clean

Comment: Please check path of class “BankManagerLogin” in Testng xml. It should be “PackangeName.ClassName”

Comment: .Thanks for the analysis!!!
Had a check on path and looks perfect "com.w2a.testcases.BankManagerLogin",
Tried cleaning project but i get same exception.

Comment: Please try to clean project in Eclipse as i mentioned. Clean with maven too if you are using.

Comment: As suggested tried on Maven too but it fails agian.
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-18T18:59:50+05:30
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project DataDrivenFramework: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: 
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.w2a.testcases.BankManagerLogin

Comment: it seems to bug in testng plugin. Please try to reinstall it and run again if clean is not working

Comment: Ok, finally uninstalling and re install worked but only works as a Maven test but even now fails while running test on TestNG suite. Strange behavior.

Comment: Ok let me add all possiblities

Comment: Please try with 4 point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason of this exception is `packageName.classname in Testng.xml is not equal to actual file location packageName.classname`. If it is same at both place then there is many possibilities for this issue.

1. Just do `Eclipse> Project > Clean` and then run the test cases again.
   It should work.

> What it does in background is, that it will call mvn
>       eclipse:clean in your project directory which will delete your
>       .project and .classpath files and you can also do a mvn
>       eclipse:eclipse - this regenerates your .project and .classpath
>       files. Thus adding the desired class in the classpath.

2. Sometime, we have got Installed  `testng plugin for eclipse` which has
   bug. Solution is same mention in first point.

> Eclipse> Project > Clean

3. Sometime `clean` project with `maven`  and `update` it also help

> Clean the project (Right click on pom.xml and clean) And update the
>   maven project (Project > Maven > Update Maven Project)

4.Adding src and test directory in `Pom.xml` under `build` tag also help

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>
         (...)
        <plugins>
            (...)
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**How it works**

> Maven provides TestNG with the directory of where those packages are
>   potentially stored, and then TestNG starts looking recursively. Even
>   just providing ${baseDir} should work. It seems the issue is not
>   providing a directory at all. I am not sure where it looks by default,
>   but providing a valid directory within the project allows TestNG to
>   spider through and find the location of the packages. Maven is then
>   able to build the changes from each package into the target/ folder
>   and run

5. running the command for `testng.xml` file from command prompt,
   please check the following if you are missing them

   a)  In the command prompt, make sure you are navigating to the folder where you have placed the `testng.xml` file.
   b)  after navigating to that, set `CLASSPATH` and include the `testng jar` file location, `selenium-server jar` file location(if you are working with selenium webdriver), `bin folder` location of your project which contains all the `.class` files of your project.

   c)  e.g., set `CLASSPATH=C:\Selenium\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar;C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar;C:\SeleniumTests\YourProject\bin`
   d)  Now run the command `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`.
6. If you are running `testng test cases` from `Eclipse or other IDE` just
   cross check you have pointing `correct testng.xml` in `Run Configuration`
   (mostly happen if we have multiple testng project in workspace)
7. Sometime uninstall and reinstall `testng plugin` will also solve
   issue.

Comment: Try it and let me know. If it serve your purpose then please don’t forget to accept as answer and upvote to help SO community. It can help people in future with similar problem.

Comment: The above answer worked for me, how do i accept the answer? is there any option to upvote? please suggest...i'm not familiar with the process.

Comment: how to Accept and upvote see here...https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow/86979

Comment: Please mention in comment which way you have resolved it. It would be helpful in people in future.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Running test classes individually passed, but running them all from the XML file kept failing with Null pointer.
What I did to solve the issue.
in my baseTest.class, I changed:

```
@BeforeTest to @BeforeMethod and
@AfterTest to @AfterMethod
```

This solved the issue for me.
What happens is that you need to open a new webdriver before launching each test method. BeforeTest tries to use the same webdriver session for all classes in one run, where a null exception occurs.

and to be sure it runs all the time before each test/method add this:

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
```